# Sum values of 2 columns OLEDB ACCESS

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, ms-access, oledb

So guys, I'm doing a simple donation project. I need to add the value of the donation table to the total value of the cashier. I did some tests and couldn't. Follows the code below.

```
    private void bntAddDonation_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        connection = new OleDbConnection(db);

        try
        {
            connection.Open();

            query = "UPDATE CX SET CX.Valor_Caixa = (SELECT SUM (DONATION.Valor_Contribuicao) FROM Contribuicao DONATION WHERE DONATION.Id_Caixa = CX.Id_Caixa) FROM Caixa CX";

            cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, connection);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            connection.Close();

            MessageBox.Show("Contribuição adicionada com sucesso!");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
```

CATCH ERROR

> Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '(SELECT SUM (DONATION.Valor_Contribuicao) FROM Contribuicao DONATION WHERE
>   DONATION.Id_Caixa = CX.Id_Caixa) FROM CAIXA CX

Comment: Does your DML work if you run it in a normal SQL editor?  Add some try-catch blocks and see what (if any) exceptions are occurring.  Not strictly related to your question, but to future proof this you want to implement iDisposable and wrap your object instantiations in `using` statements.  Also, and this is getting way ahead, but unless this is a crazy simplistic project, consider separating your data layer from your UI in another project.

Comment: I need to add the donated amount to the cashier.
I uploaded the exception that came up.

Comment: I did a test in SQL and it works, but in OLEDB passes an exception

Comment: You probably know this, but your issue is in the DML...  what DBMS is this, Oracle?

Comment: Aah, okay.  Use ms-access tag for Microsoft Access next time.  Access is literally for issues on access (like security).

Comment: I am using Access

Comment: SO expects that error messages be included as text, not screenshots, so that they're searchable. Please set a breakpoint in the `catch` block, copy the exception message (`ex.Message`), and quote it in the post body.

Comment: Sorry to doubt you, but does that command seriously execute without error?  Admittedly, MS Access is not my DBMS of choice, but I can't make heads or tails of that command.  Can you include your table structures and some relevant rows of data?

Comment: I updated the post, removed the image and copied the error message.

Comment: @Hambone: It looks like it's trying to update each `Caixa` record with the sum of `Valor_Contribuicao` from all child `Contribuicao` records using a really funky nested query that references the `CX` alias. Does that sound right? DROPE: I'll re-assert that storing a sum is rarely appropriate because it can become outdated. One of the benefits of a relational database is that you can calculate derivative values on the fly so they're never out of date.

Comment: @madreflection -- I think you nailed it.  This makes sense now.  This is invoking a correlated subquery of sorts to do the update.  Very interesting.  I didn't know this syntax was legal

Comment: Thank you. I was totally spacing on the term "correlated subquery". It might be in SQL Server. I've seen similar things, but I prefer to use a CTE to prep the data and then `MERGE` to update it. I doubt Access supports those, though, and this is questionable to me.

Comment: I'm with you...  when you said that I thought CTE all the way.  Well, this has been a fun diversion on what I should be working on.  I have a thought and am testing if it will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I totally missed the boat on your table structures, your update statement does not work.  Here is a screen shot of running the query you listed in your code and the same error .NET threw:

[image]

So here is my thought...  create a query that comes up with the totals you want in your target table.  Taking literally what you have, that would look like this:

```
SELECT CAIXA.Id_Caixa, Sum(Contribuicao.Valor_Contribuicao) AS SumOfValor_Contribuicao
FROM CAIXA INNER JOIN Contribuicao ON CAIXA.Id_Caixa = Contribuicao.Id_Caixa
GROUP BY CAIXA.Id_Caixa;
```

I am not precisely sure why `CAIXA` is even needed since the join condition is on the `Id_Caixa` field, but for continuity I kept it there.

My initial thought was to do the update query against this query (kind of like a view), but it threw some weird error, and I had to convert the query above into a make-table query:

```
SELECT CAIXA.Id_Caixa, Sum(Contribuicao.Valor_Contribuicao) AS SumOfValor_Contribuicao INTO Totals
FROM CAIXA INNER JOIN Contribuicao ON CAIXA.Id_Caixa = Contribuicao.Id_Caixa
GROUP BY CAIXA.Id_Caixa;
```

So the resulting table is named `Totals`.

From here, a simple update query should update those totals.  Notice the syntax is very different than what you have listed above...

```
UPDATE CAIXA
INNER JOIN Totals ON CAIXA.Id_Caixa = Totals.Id_Caixa
SET CAIXA.Valor_Caixa = [Totals].[SumOfValor_Contribuicao];
```

This worked for me, pre-supposing @madreflection is right, and I am guessing that is the case.

Are you SURE this is MS Access?  None of this looks like Access.  Is Access linked to some other back-end database (because if it is, this would all be a lot easier).

Comment: Thanks, I was able to solve my problem with your tips.

Comment: I'm glad.  The curious part of me wants to know if there were missing pieces to the puzzle.  If you can share in 500 characters or less, I'd welcome the feedback